# Large error bar distorts axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis, error-bars

Overall, my error bars work. However, one error value is relatively high and results in additional space on the y-axis (below y=0). I would like my axis to also look like the one on the right:
[image]

My code for the left (and problematic) graph:

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        enlargelimits=0.15,
        ylabel={Time (min)},
        symbolic x coords={Alone, Team, Pair Progr.},
        xtick=data,
        bar width=18pt
    ]
    \addplot+[
        red!75!green!50!blue!25!black!80,fill=red!75!green!50!blue!25,
        error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
    ] coordinates {
        (Alone, 12.88) +- (0, 3.74)
        (Team, 15) +- (0, 14.52) 
        (Pair Progr., 19) +- (0, 7.43) 
    };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Time needed for the task. \\(n=8)}
  \label{fig:time}
 \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
```

-> if I reduce the value of Team from 14.52 to something smaller like 7 the graph looks normal again

Comment: You should give the rest of your code. This does not compile as it is.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the size of error bar and it does not correct when you reduce the 14.52 to a lower value. It is due to the enlargelimits. I removed the messy figure in the minipage in the resizebox.

enlargelimits does exactly what you don't want (but is what you might sometimes want for example if plot data points are straddling the axis)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        %enlargelimits=0.15,
        ylabel={Time (min)},
        symbolic x coords={Alone, Team, Pair Progr.},
        xtick=data,
        bar width=18pt,
       ymin=0,
    ]
    \addplot+[
        red!75!green!50!blue!25!black!80,fill=red!75!green!50!blue!25,
        error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
    ] coordinates {
        (Alone, 12.88) +- (0, 3.74)
        (Team, 15) +- (0, 14.52)
        (Pair Progr., 19) +- (0, 7.43)
    };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]